# Trigger native click() and not Selenium click() on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I am writing a test case and accessing a Selenium WebElement as follows -

```
 WebElement printButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Print']"));
```

Now I want to perform a click on the above element but I don't want to use selenium's click(). I want to use a lower level Javascript or JQuery's click().

For this I converted the WebElement into a String that contains the element in its HTML form -

```
String s = printButton.getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

The value stored in this String is `"<span>Print<span>"`.

Now I am stuck. I am aware that there is a Selenium function `driver.executeScript();` but Im not sure how to do it.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as that :)

```
 WebElement printButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Print']"));
 driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", printButton);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I get an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
As mentioned in the question above, when i print the String i get "<span>Print</span>". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from where ? stacktrace? if the xpath you provided is the print button, then this script will click it.